LED dimmer driver board
I am all very new to the electrical stuff and perhaps this is an advanced project but hopefully someone can at least point me in the right direction.
I am looking to create a PCB that will allow me to connect 20 other boards via terminals and drive the LEDs on these boards. The driver board should also have a potentiometer which will allow to change the brightness of the LEDs on the connected boards.
The boards that will be connected to the driver board will have SMD LEDs placed on them behind the text on engraved acrylic panels to backlight the text. So up to 20 LEDs might be on each of the connected boards, making it 400 LEDs to be driven by the driver board.
I was looking at the 555 timer with a MOSFET but, from what I can understand, this can only handle around 200 mA. The required circuit needs to handle up to 8 A, assuming 20 mA per LED.
I am hoping to use the same power supply as I am using for the some of the boards as the MAX7219 chips are used on some of the boards to drive 7-segment displays that are connected to Arduino. The power supply I currently have is rated at 5 V 20 A.
I could not find any solutions to my problem as all tutorials only show 1..8 LEDs.

I think a lot of problems will be avoided if you move away from the 5V supply and run all the LEDs in each board in one or two series strings. That would allow you to use a single cheap LED driver chip that could handle your global brightness adjustment and not have to worry about 400 separate current limiting devices and managing the brightness levels across them all.

If you use 12v constant voltage LEDs for the boards (which could even be led strips), you can buy a commercial dimmer with a control pot for a few dollars online.

@vir what driver would you suggest me to get clued up on then? Should I move onto a 12V supply ?
